Why do we only use the principal quantum number to calculate the energy of an electron in an H atom?
According to my high school textbook the energy of an electron in a hydrogen atom is $E = -13.6/n^2~\pu{eV}$, where $n$ is the principal quantum number of the orbital in which the electron is present.
But the energy of an electron increases as the azimuthal quantum number increases for a fixed principal quantum number. Then why is only the principal quantum number used to calculate the energy of an electron?

It is unclear what resources you have consulted before asking this question and what conclusion you have made from that.

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/180113/what-is-a-degenerate-orbital

In the hydrogen atom, the energy of an electron depends only on the principal quantum number. But this is only true for the hydrogen atom. For all heavier atoms, the energy of an electron depends also on the azimuthal quantum number, because of the interaction between electrons.

Do the Zeeman and Stark splitting have potential to influence that answer? Sorry, this is outside my field of expertise.

The Schrödinger equation for the hydrogen atom is usually solved without interaction with outer magnetic or electric fields, so out of the influence of Zeemann and Stark splitting.
